# Is it possible to make oracle database procedures to ignore commit statements?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql, transactions

I'm working on Java application that integrates with legacy system written Oracle PL/SQL. Unfortunately i'm not able to change this legacy system. Problem with this system is that it that sometimes COMMIT statements are written into procedures. But this causes that I'm not able to handle transactions correctly on my application level.

So is it possible to make oracle database procedures to ignore commit statements?

I have found that when doing   `ALTER SESSION DISABLE COMMIT IN PROCEDURE` in beginning of connection will cause exception when PL/SQL procedure is trying to commit. But is it possible to make Oracle to ignore commit without changing PL/SQL code?

Comment: Uhm, why do you want to do that?

Comment: @fge, if the procedure commits, the calling transaction cannot rollback if a subsequent action causes an error.

Comment: _"I'm not able to change this legacy system"_ but disabling the `COMMIT` statements in the application is not a change?

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you can do that. You'll have to add a parameter to those procedures like"do commit"with a default value true. And you call them with parameter set to false. Pass the parameter value on, if they are nested. That way the legacy code still behaves the same but you get transaction control.

Answer (score 6):

I'm working with Oracle for 9 years now. I also checked undocumented parameters regarding your question and I'm pretty sure, that there is no way to let Oracle ignore a commit of a stored procedure.

But of cause, theroretical you could use Oracle's flashback feature (e.g. flashback database or flashback table), to reset whole database or single tables to a state before your transaction began. But be aware, that this only works as desired, if you are the only one, who changes anything at the objects you flash back. This is usually unrealistic. By the way you also need to consider that the flashback feature is not designed to support such a scenario, so performance of your application will be suboptimal in case you need to flashback anything. 
But this may be a way to solve your problem, if you have no other choice.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best thing is to alter the pl/sql procedures without affecting current functionality.  In other words, add a new parameter to allow the user to ignore commits, but default to existing functionality (to commit).  I've done this in a similar situation and it worked well.

So, you'd have something like:

```
create or replace procedure some_proc(
    i_num in number, -- existing parameter
    i_commit in number default 1) -- perform commit? 0=false, else true
as

begin
  -- some DML here

  if (i_commit <> 0) then
    commit;
  end if;

end;
```

Make sure that this new parameter is added to the end of the param list.  So your app would pass in 0 (false) for i_commit.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

> I have found that when doing `ALTER SESSION DISABLE COMMIT IN PROCEDURE`
>   in beginning of connection will cause exception when PL/SQL procedure
>   is trying to commit.

Yeah, the documented behaviour of that statement is to force ORA-00034 exceptions if a procedure attempts to issue a commit.  I think it's really intended as a testing thing, to identify procedures with embedded commits.

I think it is widely regarded as bad practice for stored procedures to issue commits.  Control of the transaction must belong to the top of the calling stack.

Unfortunately there is no way to ignore those embedded commits.  You will either have to re-write the PL/SQL routines, or else code some workarounds in your calling code (e.g. exception handler which issues additional DML to reverse committed changes).

Answer (score 0):

Knowing what the procedure did would have been helpful.
However, assuming that the procedure modifies data in a limited number of tables(That's what we mostly do in PLSQL anyway), you could try running a flashback query on that schema:

FLASHBACK TABLE TABLE_NAME TO TIMESTAMP(TO_DATE('06-SEP-2012 23:59:59','DD-MON-YYYY HH24: MI: SS'));

You can set the time string "06-SEP-2012 23:59:59" to the time just before the procedure is called in your JAVA code.

Its a bad workaround, but worth a try I guess

Comment: This isn't much more information than in existing answers.  You could expand on them by building a solution that only rolls back a specific transaction.  Perhaps by using `VERSIONS_XID`, or with `dbms_application_info.set_client_info` and audit triggers to manually undo a set of changes, or with logminer.  That may not directly solve the question of how to ignore a commit, but it would be a great work-around and worthy of the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm working on Java application that integrates with legacy system
>   written Oracle PL/SQL. Unfortunately i'm not able to change this
>   legacy system.

Hmmm, this smells like politics... "Don't touch this, it works!" I guess. :(

As a matter of fact, it's most likely impossible to ignore a `COMMIT` statement, as @Tilman Fliegel (and others) already said. And if it was, it would be quite an ugly wart in your codebase.

I'm not that good at politics, but I'd say if you *cannot use nor change this*, then *just don't use this*. I mean:

- If you cannot change your procedures because they are used by other (old, immutable) systems, then duplicate them, then modify/refactor your copy until you're happy with it. If you're able to make your version retro-compatible, you may even provide a way for other (old) systems to use yours afterwards, when/if they are refactored: just introduce a "legacy mode" input parameter or whatever, cf. other answers.
- If you cannot change code because you cannot understand/test it, then this is a major issue. It may even be safer to just trash it and start over from scratch (provided you're able to do so).

But maybe trying to ignore the `COMMIT`s is easier after all. Humans are so hard to refactor... ;)